# what techniques does Solr use to index files?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, search-engine

as you know, there are different technique to index documents for search engines. 
such as inverted index, Distributed Dynamic Indexing, Semantic Indexing, NGram Indexing, Context Indexing, Big Data, Multilingual Indexing and so on.
I am working with Solr now. I wonder which techniques does Solr use to index documents and  how does Solr (or Lucene) use these techniques?

Answer (score 1):

First - this is a very wide area and most of the terms you're listing isn't index types. They describe product features (or buzzwords) that could be supported regardless of how the index is built behind the scene.

Solr uses Lucene - which at the core is an inverted index.

> The index stores statistics about terms in order to make term-based search more efficient. Lucene's index falls into the family of indexes known as an inverted index. This is because it can list, for a term, the documents that contain it. This is the inverse of the natural relationship, in which documents list terms.

There is also many support structures in place to make Lucene even more efficient for certain queries and features. On such feature is the [DocValues support](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues) - which can be described as a column oriented store with document -> term mappings to speed up things like faceting.

You can see most of these support features in the [Codecs API Doc for Lucene 6.3.0](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/package-summary.html). As it's quite a large list, I'll leave it out from the comment itself.

Answer (score 1):

To answer **which techniques** - Under the hood , **Solr** uses **Lucene**  APIs and Lucene indexing technique is - **Inverted Indexing**. Solr is simply a complete application with infrastructure wrapper but underlying document indexing technique is the one provided by Lucene APIs.

**How does Solr (or Lucene) use these techniques?**

[Here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/building-a-search-index-with-lucene.html) is a nice overview of Lucene indexing for beginners. Its just a very simplistic overview but explains the basics.

Since Solr is a product, most of its available documentations are functional ones ( not explaining actual indexing techniques etc) and since raw usage of Lucene is minimal, Lucene documentation is not up to the mark so most of the time, one needs to dig Lucene code or API documentation to understand working of Lucene.

Hope it helps !!